# TRUNC results wrong value for 0 decimals

Tags: sql, oracle, math, numbers

I didn't find answer when I search for below situation. I have a simple value to be rounded to 0 decimals. I try below queries in oracle and get as shown below:

```
select 1 / 3 * 19608 CORRECT from dual;
--6536 is correct

select TRUNC(1 / 3 * 19608, 0) WRONG from dual;
 --6535 which is wrong

select TRUNC(1 / 3 * 19608, 2) WRONG from dual;
 --6535.99 which is wrong
```

Please let me know if you have a question linked to this situation.

---

**UPDATES**

Sorry to reject your answers. I found one more issue for which your answers remains invalid:

```
select TRUNC(1 / 3 * 15, 0) WRONG from dual;
--5 is correct
```

I am getting correct numbers for small numbers. Which I expect to give wrong as well because 19608 results in wrong values. Is 19608 a magic number ?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I understood the mathematics being explained in below answer. But I still doubt on the oracle TRUNC function which is not giving right output as expected. Now, I want to illustrate this with an example as below:

```
SELECT ( (4500 + ROWNUM) * 3) multiple_3,
       TRUNC (1 / 3 * ( (4500 + ROWNUM) * 3), 2) result_with_trunc,
       1 / 3 * ( (4500 + ROWNUM) * 3) no_trunc
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY 4500 + ROWNUM < 6000
```

In above SQL you can check the result; exact after 500 row, the oracle behaves different to numbers which are divisible by 3. 
If below answer is true than, it means 15000 is completely divisible by 3 and 15003 is **not** completely divisible by 3.

I hope this is making some sense which isn't related to any mathematics.

---

**UPDATE 3**

A simple and direct question can be as follow:

```
SQL> set numwidth 50
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(1 / 3 * 15000, 50) FROM dual;

                               TRUNC(1/3*15000,50)
--------------------------------------------------
                                              5000

SQL> SELECT TRUNC(1 / 3 * 15003, 50) FROM dual;

                               TRUNC(1/3*15003,50)
--------------------------------------------------
         5000.999999999999999999999999999999999999
```

Why is my oracle client (11.2.0.1.0) and server (11g 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit) is giving different results for same operations on a number which is divisible by 3 ?

---

**LAST UPDATE - Accepted answer**

@[Lalit Kumar B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3989608/lalit-kumar-b) thanks for stressing on recurring decimal numbers. 
The case I encountered is not a fault of oracle. The trunc is properly doing its work. 
The problem is 0.3333.... fraction multiplied to a number divisible by 3 but not completely. Few examples of such numbers are 300, 15003, etc.,

Thus, the results of *ORACLE TRUNC FUNCTION* are correct when applied on fractional numbers resulted by multiplication with 1/3*X, where X is not completely divisible by 3.

Comment: Should it be 0? 1 / 3 = 0 and 0 * 19608 = 0...

Comment: Nope. It is giving me as expected but just one less the value.

Comment: Oracle math abilities are far from dedicated software like Matlab. Since 1/3 is periodic (both in base 10 and base 2) you need to rewrite your logic so none of its steps require infinite floating point storage.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario : Thanks. Your solution work. I made it TRUNC(19608 * 1/3, 0) and it gave correct result. But can you suggest some thing with out changing the logic to get correct value.

Comment: The key point is that Oracle doesn't understand fractions so it'll just evaluate from left to right and will lose precision at `1/3`. Doing `19608/3` works fine because it has integer solution. Another solution would be to round rather than truncate. What's better, basically depends on your exact needs.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario ,  I accept your answers. Thanks for below explanation on answer as well.

Comment: Sorry @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I found a new issue now. I updated the description above.

Comment: @Abs Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the query, nor with the output. it is your ***client*** which is rounding of the value in your first query's output.

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(1 / 3 * 19608, 50) FROM dual;

TRUNC(1/3*19608,50)
-------------------
               6536

SQL> set numwidth 50
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(1 / 3 * 19608, 50) FROM dual;

                               TRUNC(1/3*19608,50)
--------------------------------------------------
         6535.999999999999999999999999999999999999

SQL>
```

In my **SQL*Plus** client, I have adjusted the **numwidth** and you can see the actual value.

Also, in Oracle there is limit to the **scale** for **NUMBER datatype** to which you can have 100% accuracy. And that limit is 38 digits, post which you cannot have 100% accuracy. You need to understand **mantissa** and **exponent**. In this case, **scale** places a limit on the possible minimum of **exponent**.

**Update** OP updated the question.

> select TRUNC(1 / 3 * 15, 0) WRONG from dual;
>   --5 is correct

It has nothing to with Oracle. It is pure **mathematics**. `15` is completely divisible by `3` and hence you get a **whole number** `5` as result.

> Is 19608 a magic number ?

`19608` is not **completely divisible** by `3`, you will have **fractional part**. I have already shown above. The correct result for `(1/3)*19608` is **NOT** `6536`. The correct result is `6535.9` with **recurring decimal**. It is never completely divisible by 3.

**Update 2** OP updated the question.

```
SQL> set numwidth 50
SQL> SELECT (1/3)*5000*3 FROM dual;

                                      (1/3)*5000*3
--------------------------------------------------
         5000.000000000000000000000000000000000001

SQL> SELECT (1/3)*(5000*3) FROM dual;

                                    (1/3)*(5000*3)
--------------------------------------------------
                                              5000

SQL> SELECT trunc((1/3)*(5000*3),2) FROM dual;

                           TRUNC((1/3)*(5000*3),2)
--------------------------------------------------
                                              5000

SQL> SELECT 1 / 3 * 15003 FROM dual;

                                         1/3*15003
--------------------------------------------------
         5000.999999999999999999999999999999999999

SQL> SELECT 15003/3 FROM dual;

                                           15003/3
--------------------------------------------------
                                              5001
```

The reason for different results in the above queries for *similar*(**not same**) operations is that Oracle evaluates from left to right.

When you do `1/3*n`, Oracle evaluates it differently from `n/3`. In the former case, `1/3` is evaluated first, thus creating a **[recurring non-terminating decimal number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375687/0-333333-a-recurring-or-non-terminating-decimal)** `0.3333....` where `3` is recurring digit. Now, when you multiply it with a number which is multiple of `3`, it has already lost the **precision**, therefore the final result will also be recurring non-terminating number.

When you put it inside the braces, you are asking Oracle to explicitly evaluate the portion inside the brace and not just left to right. Hence, the below two are **not evaluated** the same way in Oracle:

```
1 / 3 * 15003
```

is not evaluated the same way as

```
15003/3
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But my concern is why a perfectly divisible number of 3 is showing me wrong values. Why the first number is considered rather than dividing the second number directly by 3. Hope you can give some solution without doing code changes.

Comment: @Abs Most computers programs are not that smart. Since `*` and `/` have the same precedence Oracle evaluates from left to right: `1/3*19608` = `0.33333...*19608`. No longer integers! Oracle doesn't know that he could rewrite the expression to `19608/3`.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B, Please see above updates. Sorry to reject your answer.

Comment: @lalit-kumar-b may be I forgot numbers since long time back I left my college. Now I started again with 1. Thanks for reminding me of basics. I would request ***YOU** to post some basic of mathematics that I understood wrong in your above explanation.

Comment: @Abs Looking ta your updated question 2, once again. It is your client which is rounding off the digits. For one last time, open **SQL*Plus**, do the following : `set numwidth 50` and then run the sql.

Comment: @lalit-kumar-b that correct about my client. And I am willing to know why the oracle client is doing it different to two similar numbers.

Comment: @Abs I have updated my answer to explain. I hope it should remove any confusion with the way Oracle evaluates.